# Why is 'Delayed::Job.all' not being recognized in the Ruby on Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job

I'm currently trying to check to see what is in my delayed job queue but when I run `Delayed::Job.all` in the console, I get a `NameError: uninitialized constant Delayed` error.  According to the readme on the github page, I should be able to run normal delayed_job commands.

I'm currently using the `delayed_job_mongoid` gem version 1.0.8.

Here is my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'mongoid', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'bson_ext' # mongoid-related

gem 'bcrypt-ruby' # encryption
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'

gem 'delayed_job_mongoid', :git => 'https://github.com/asavartsov/delayed_job_mongoid.git'

group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'mongoid-rspec'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'guard-spork'
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just tried to do that and it worked – I got a mongoid criteria. Are you using bungler? rvm? how are you running the rails console?

Comment: What version of Mongoid are you running? I had some issues getting the 3.x branch running with the latest delayed_job_mongoid gem, so I ended up using a branch that someone else had fixed up (git://github.com/asavartsov/delayed_job_mongoid.git)...

Comment: You probably included delayed_job only in :production group in Gemfile

Comment: I've included delayed_job_mongoid for no specific environment and I'm using the forked branch at /asavartsov/delayed_job_mongoid.git.  I'm not using rvm or bungler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy-pasted your Gemfile and it works for me:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Delayed::Job.all
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
   selector: {},
   options:  {},
   class:    Delayed::Backend::Mongoid::Job,
   embedded: false>
```

You may try to include the DelayedJob itself (although the delayed_job_mongoid requires it in its gemspec), e.g.

```
gem 'delayed_job'
```

So either you have some weird stuff in config/initializers/*.rb , or in the config/application.rb or config/environments/production.rb